# My google cloud instance lost network connectivity

Tags: google-compute-engine

My google cloud instance (10.128.0.3) lost network connectivity somewhere just after 0400 this AM.  I am running Centos 6.10) The network interfaces are up and have IP addresses.  Unable to ping default gateway (10.128.0.1).  Firewall rules (google and local)  have not been changed/modified.  This instance has been online for several years with no recent changes made.  Any suggestions would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. My Google Compute engine instance was running Centos 6.9 and the update caused the installation of 6.10 now I lost network connectivity.

Here's kernel log:

martian source 10.162.0.6 from 69.x.x.x, on dev eth0
ll header: xx:xx:xx:xx:00:06:xx:01:xx:a2:00:xx:08:00
Jul  6 23:01:31 my-instance kernel: martian source 10.162.0.6 from 69.x.x.x, on dev eth0
Jul  6 23:01:31 my-instance kernel: ll header: xx:01:xx:a2:xx:xx:xx:01:xx:a2:00:xx:xx:00

I tried creating a new instance from Google Centos 6 image and a soon as the update process kick in it break the networking.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue when updating to kernel 2.6.32-754 that is affecting both Red Hat, and CentOS images, and seems related to this DHCP update. The Compute Engine team are already aware of this issue.

Meanwhile, and in addition to the great suggestions above, you may also use a startup script ( add the default gateway IP address) to fix this issue, and then restart your instance. Todo so without access to the instance simply add a metadata for the instance with the name startup-script and the content of the below script (make sure to update the gateway to your, it can be found in the VPC Page)

```
#!/bin/bash
route add default gw [default_gateway_ip] eth0
```

For further information/updates about this issue, you may check this issue tracker link. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111154121

Comment: I'd just like to also link the bug report on Red Hat's website: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1595412